# how to enable applicaton bar on navigating back from a page in windows phone 8.1 application using winjs+html

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I'm creating an application where my landing page needs application bar, but other pages do not need it.
I'm able to disable the application bar when i enter the page,but not able to enable it back when i navigate back to main page. application bar is in default.html and applied all over the applicaton.
I'm using the following code to disable the application bar:

```js
    WinJS.UI.processAll(element)
       .then(function () {
            appbar = document.getElementById("appBar");
           if (appbar !== undefined || appbar !== null) {
               appbar.winControl.disabled = "true";
           }
       });
```

please suggest me on how to enable the application bar when i navigate back to the landing page(main page).

Thanks in Advance
Swetha

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do about it. I noticed that sometimes the app bar from my previous page is still loaded, so what I do is name every app bar with an unique name I can then search for with `getElementById` and disable every other AppBar that is not the one I want to show, then I enable the one I need to show.

I believe your code is right, you just need to disable the right appBar, which it might not be the one you are disabling